# Images not changing on new search. C# (asp.net project)

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, arraylist

This uses bing's web service. I have a single image button and  an array of image buttons. The single changes each time it is clicked to the next image in the array. The problem is if I click it and do a new search the array of image buttons does not change.
CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using bing_search.net.bing.api;
using System.Collections;




namespace bing_search
{

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    static ArrayList images = new ArrayList();
    static Image[] imagearry;
    static ImageButton[] imgButtnsArray;
    static int counter = 0;
    int fooBarCount = 0;
    int firstLoad = 0; 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }

    protected void DoItButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        images.Clear();
        imagearry = null; 
        imgButtnsArray = null;

        BingService bs = new BingService(); 
        net.bing.api.SearchRequest req = new SearchRequest();
        req.AppId = "0B15AB60D625A10059A4A04B68615C5B0D904CA9";
        req.Query = SearchBox.Text;
        req.Sources = new SourceType[] { SourceType.Image};
        req.Market = "en-us";
        req.Adult = AdultOption.Off;
        req.Image = new ImageRequest();
        req.Image.CountSpecified = true;
        req.Image.Count = 50;

        SearchResponse resp = bs.Search(req);
        foreach (ImageResult result in resp.Image.Results)
        {
            Image im = new Image();
            im.ImageUrl = result.MediaUrl;
            im.Width = 200;
            im.Height = 200;
            images.Add(im);
            //this.Controls.Add(im);

        }
      //  Image lol = (Image)images[0];



        int size = images.Count; 
        imagearry = new Image[size];
        Type typ = typeof(Image);
        imagearry = (Image [])images.ToArray(typ); 
        ImageButton1.ImageUrl = imagearry[0].ImageUrl;
        int blaCount = 0;
        ArrayList imgButtns = new ArrayList(); 
        foreach (Image ii in images)
        {
            ImageButton imgb = new ImageButton();
            imgb.Width = 200;
            imgb.Height = 200;
            imgButtns.Add(imgb);    
        }
        size = imgButtns.Count;
        imgButtnsArray = (ImageButton[])imgButtns.ToArray(typeof(ImageButton));

        foreach (ImageButton iii in imgButtnsArray)
        {
            imgButtnsArray[fooBarCount].ImageUrl = imagearry[fooBarCount].ImageUrl;
            Panel1.Controls.Add(iii);
            fooBarCount++;

        }
        fooBarCount = 0;
        counter = 0;

    }


     protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        heightLable.Text = "clicked";
        Image tempImage = (Image)imagearry[counter];
        ImageButton1.ImageUrl = tempImage.ImageUrl;
        foreach (ImageButton iii in imgButtnsArray)
        {
            imgButtnsArray[fooBarCount].ImageUrl = imagearry[fooBarCount].ImageUrl;
            Panel1.Controls.Add(iii);
            fooBarCount++;

        }
        fooBarCount = 0;
        counter = 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: do you have to be using an ArrayList? You've got a using statement for System.Collections.Generic, and Linq, so you're using .net 3.5+ -- just use a List<T>. Also, there's no reason to make your member variables static

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for something like that. I just started messing with .net and am used to vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed  ImageButton1_Click to this and now it works. thanks for the quick responses. Back to playing with .net

```
     protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
     {
        counter++;
        heightLable.Text = "clicked";
        Image tempImage = (Image)imagearry[counter];
        ImageButton1.ImageUrl = tempImage.ImageUrl;
        //Random RandomNumber = new Random(10000);
        foreach (ImageButton iii in imgButtnsArray)
        {
           Panel1.Controls.Add((Image)imagearry[fooBarCount]);
            fooBarCount++;
        }
        fooBarCount = 0;
        counter = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You reset both counters on every click, so its always starts from the same image.

```
fooBarCount = 0;
    counter = 0;
```

also they are not static, so they reset to 0 anyway on every page load, and show the same image and not change.

If from the other hand the cache is the problem, because I can not know whats the image file name, and maybe this is the issue here, then try something like.

> imgButtnsArray[fooBarCount].ImageUrl =
>   imagearry[fooBarCount].ImageUrl +
>   "?rnd=" + RandomNumber.ToString();

Comment: Hmmm... still seems to have the same issue. Thing I don't understand is shouldn't that array list be empty when the new search is preformed, because I used the clear method?